# angular how to let html redner the scope variable as a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

Say I have the following line in a controller hmmCtrl:

```
$rootScope.value = 1;
$scope.hmm = "{{$root.value}}"
```

And in html, if I have:

```
<section ng-controller="hmmCtrl">
 {{hmm}}
</section>
```

Currently it displays:

```
{{$root.value}}
```

but I actually want to see the value of $root.value:

```
1
```

In the long run I plan to put the $root.value in a json file that is going to be parsed by the hmmCtrl.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: From a quick look it seems You have a typo it should be $scope.hmm = $rootScope.value not root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you can do is, you can write a inside a controller which can return your interpolation expression evaluated value

**Code**

```
//inject `$interpolate` inside controller function before using it.
$scope.evaluateValue = function(expr){
   return $interpolate(expr)($scope);
}
```

**Markup**

```
<section ng-controller="hmmCtrl">
  {{evaluateValue(hmm)}}
</section>
```

**Other way**

```
<section ng-controller="hmmCtrl" ng-bind="evaluateValue(hmm)">
</section>
```

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/jBb6Kvf6vXjjNQ6I3sUe?p=preview)

Comment: hmm, this prints out evaluateValue(hmm)  to me - I put the $scope.eveluateValue inside hmmCtrl.

Comment: Hmm, the updated works as the value can be shown now, but the console gives error: Error: f is undefined
h@http://localhost:81/js/angular_core/angular.min.v.1.4.5.js:94:218
$scope.evaluate@http://localhost:81/js/controllers/menu_controllers.js:11:11

where menu_controllers.js:11 is the line of 
return $interpolate(expr)($scope);

any ideas?

Comment: Have yoi injected $interpolate service in controller?

Comment: yes - the value is correctly interpolated; just with the f is undefined error.

Comment: Could you please create a plunkr?

Comment: @jamesdeath123 I also added Demo, please check the same

Answer (score 0):

Change your html-Code from

```
<section ng-controller="hmmCtrl">
    {{hmm}}
</section>
```

to

```
<section ng-controller="hmmCtrl">
    {{value}}
</section>
```

$scope inherites from $rootScope, meaning $scope also has the "value"-variable...

Comment: Although your answer is right that $scope inherits from $rootScope and it also have "value", it doesn't solve the problem of parsing "{{$root.value}}" or "{{$scope.value}}" properly, which is the real problem I tried to ask..

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't know where $root came from and misunderstood it as $rootScope. My bad^^